# Make with silent output on specific target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a `run:` target in my makefile that simply runs my compiled executable. This target would then have that executable as a dependency and would compile it if it did not exist.

How can I silence the compilation output (such as when using `@` before a command) of all commands but only when running the `run` target while still keeping the output of the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really understand the question.  An example would be very helpful.  But, suppose you have this:

```
run: binary
        ./binary
```

then you could do something like this:

```
run:
        $(MAKE) -s binary
        ./binary
```

That is convert the prerequisite to a sub-make invocation with `-s`.

I don't think there's any other way to do it.